# Windows Server Backup Snap-In Initializes/Moves Extremely Slowly

Tags: performance, windows-sbs-2011, windows-server-backup, mmc

I have an SBS-2011 box. The WSB snap-in consistently takes 10+ minutes to move beyond 'Reading Data'. After the snap-in finally initializes I experience the same behavior when performing a recovery.

Has anybody experienced this\have any ideas?

Thanks for your time & participation ! :-]

Comment: I did find some info on the SBS-Monitoring Database possibly needing to be recreated. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2011/08/22/how-to-recreate-the-sbsmonitoring-database/